# Tomcat reflecting old UI changes for Angular 8

Tags: java, angular, maven, tomcat, angular8

I have a `Spring Boot - Angular` project in which I am using maven plugin to auto install `node` and `npm` and also using the plugin to copy the content of `/angular/dist/` directory to output directory.

```
<plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>default-copy-resources</id>
                    <phase>process-resources</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>copy-resources</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <overwrite>true</overwrite>
                        <outputDirectory>${project.basedir}/src/main/webapp/</outputDirectory>
                        <resources>
                            <resource>
                                <directory>${project.basedir}/${angular.project.location}/dist</directory>
                            </resource>
                        </resources>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

I was earlier using `Angular2` but with some ui requirements, I switched to Angular 8, and now surprisingly, everytime I build the war and deploy, my old changes are getting reflected.

I tried all the necessary steps I could but this problem doesn't seem to fade away. Here is what all I tried:

1. Disabled browser cache in developer tools
2. Generate war file using `mvn clean install` instead of running directly from Eclipse
3. Used incognito mode to load the application with no luck
4. Added new tomcat (v9), checked out latest code from git, rebuild everything but it won't reflect the new changes

It is just the old labels for some dropdown elements which are not going though I have them removed in the UI files.

I am stuck with this for a very long time now. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Are you sure your dist content is copied properly. For once, try deleting the old dist content from `webapps` and manually copy the content of a fresh `dist` and see if that works ?

Comment: @SaurabhTiwari Yes, dist is getting copied properly. Have checked that as well.

Comment: That is weird then. Although you must have tried this, I suggest to have a closer look in your project again and see if the labels you are seeing on the screen are indeed coming from the files you edited. May be search entire project for some keywords around them.